# Linux GRUB2: How to resume from hibernation?

Tags: linux, hibernate, grub2

Moving to GRUB2 my Arch Linux no longer resumes from hibernation, because the actual resuming is no longer set up. In GRUB legacy I'd write:

/boot/grub/menu.lst:

```
kernel /vmlinuz26 root=/dev/disk/by-uuid/X ro resume=/dev/disk/by-uuid/Y ro
```

But with GRUB2's new way of handling the boot menu, I no longer know how, where and in which form to add this. My guess is you'd add the entire menuentry to /etc/grub.d/40_custom/ and somehow set up the resuming there? Manually hardcoding menuentries into GRUB2 seems to go against its flexible menu generation approach, but whatever reenables me to use hibernate is gladly welcomed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Open up `/etc/default/grub` with root privledges and add `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=/dev/sdXY"` Where *XY* is the swap partition location, which can be found by `sudo fdisk -l`. It looks like you are using UUID instead and that's fine. `/etc/default/grub` only affects the current operating system so don't worry about every linux OS using grub to start using that swap.
After finishing your edits, run `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` (substitute `grub.cfg` with whatever file grub reads at boot, e.g. it may be named `/boot/grub/grub.efi`) to update your grub startup information with what you changed in `/etc/default/grub`

(I don't think this needs to be done on Ubuntu) 
 **Note** that one may need to add a resume hook to make sure the kernel knows that it should resume if Archlinux or perhaps another OS is being used. To do this, if one is using mkinitcpio, go to `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` and insert `resume` in the HOOKS array before `filesystems` but after `ide`, `scsi`, and `sata`. Then, you you need to rebuild the initial ramdisk(early OS state for loading modules, including resume) image by `mkinitcpio -p linux`

**Other links that may help**
https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-to-a-swap-file 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pm-utils#Mkinitcpio_Resume_Hook

Comment: Thanks! Arch is now successfully back from hibernating again!

Comment: @xlys Glad I could help. Did you wait all these months to fix it?

Comment: Yes, I did, and I left my computer on a lot more because of it.

Comment: I had to update initramfs

`sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`

Comment: When I boot, grub gives "error: invalid file name `resume=UUID=XX...XX'. it gives the same error using resume=/dev/sdb1. Any thoughts?

Comment: Glad to see you don't have to specify `resume=UUID=<uuid>`, which means I can hiberate and restore to/from my encrypted partitions. Thanks!